# How to install an isolated or sandboxed debian package?

Tags: software-installation, security, deb

Suppose there exists a particular debian package in the Ubuntu repositories, which upon installation pulls the actual software from an external repository such as sourceforge.  The software itself appears good, but I don't trust the original author, nor the fact that it uses an installation script that downloads from an odd repository.

What would be the procedure to install such software in an isolated environment ? Assume the software is command-line only `jar` file.

Comment: I would do it either in [a system in] a virtual machine or in a separate computer.

Comment: Well, virtual machine is an obvious choice, but downloading iso and settings up a virtual machine just to test one package is too much work and time. I was hoping for something simpler like `chroot`. But yes, I could do that.

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy how you created a isolated  environment, I'm also looking for same thing, i have a `.deb` package how do i isolate it from rest of the system.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at *Firejail*:
https://firejail.wordpress.com/

You can create sandbox environments with it. There are many preconfigured profiles for different applications, but in your case you probably will have to create a custom one or try to use the restricted default profile.

Comment: A bad script could be run on installation, definitely not an option.